# Getting the chatID of the user who joins my telegram channel using Bot

Tags: c#, console-application, telegram, telegram-bot

> **I want to find out the chatID or username of the the new user who joins my telegram channel where my telegram bot is one of its
>   admins.**

Also I want to know whether I can get the users list of my channel using my bot admin or not?

Let say that I'm using NetTelegramBotApi in C#, I have tried the below code but didn't worked:

```
if (update.ChannelPost.NewChatMember != null)
{
Console.WriteLine(update.ChannelPost.NewChatMember.Id.ToString());
continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the official bot API [doesn't have](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) service messages for when a user joins a channel yet. However i would like to pint you towards [PWRTelegram](https://pwrtelegram.xyz/), which is an unofficial telegram API that allows lots of cool stuff and also allows fetching mtproto updates as a bot (Sounds impossible? well it does it). Chances are you may find a solution with it.

Comment: could you please explain how to use PWRTelegram to get channel users list?